# MongoDB query - Filter array by odd size

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Is it possible to build a query filter for documents with an array with odd size instead of this?

```
db.records.find({'$or': [{'my_array': {'$size': 1}},
                         {'my_array': {'$size': 3}},
                         {'my_array': {'$size': 5}},
                                     ...
                         {'my_array': {'$size': 15}}]}))
```

The filter may not catch all the items if you stop at a certain number.

Comment: What's your MongoDB server version?

Comment: The version is 3.0.7 @chridam .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use below aggregation query to `$project` the `size` and `data` field and use `$mod` function to keep documents with odd-sized array.

```
db.records.aggregate(
  { $project: { size:{ $size: "$my_array" }, data:"$$ROOT"} },
  { $match: { size: { $mod: [ 2, 1 ] } } }
)
```

Comment: Yes, this works. I would like to understand more this `$match` filter using `$mod`. Seems that $mod[2,1] returns 2 always. How does this filter even sizes?

Comment: You have to use mod as a filter. Take a look here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/mod/#examples. For even size document  change the remainder  from 1 to 0.

Comment: Sorry I meant odd sizes in my previous comment. The docs link clarifies everything.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `$where` to supply a Javascript expression to query:

```
db.records.find({ $where: "this.my_array.length % 2 == 1" })
```

The JavaScript expression will be processed for each document matched by the rest of the query so for performance you should try and ensure that the rest of your query is selective.